# How to download a svg file rendered on a browser as a png or jpg?

Tags: php, laravel-5, svg

I want to save the view(svg file) generated by the svgpng function as a image file(jpg or png). I tried using Imagick, but that's saying unable to load the imagick. I tried a lot but it's still saying unable to load. Is there any other way to download the svg?

Imagick error:
[image: Imagick error]

```
public function svgpng(Request $request)
{
     $id=$request->id;
     $s=stud::find($id);
        return view('sample',['studentid'=>$s]);
}
```

Comment: You have to install the imagick extension. It's not a builtin module.

Comment: I did everything possible but I'm getting the same error. Is there any other way?